# Does Space armour soak explosion damage?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e, mage-the-awakening

Does the Space Arcanum spell Untouchable protect against explosions?
The fluff indicates that the mage dodges out of harms way, but what happens when the mage in the lethal blast radius of a large explosion?

Comment: Spheres were *Mage: The Ascension*. Space is one of the ten Arcana in *Mage: The Awakening*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the ability to "hit the deck" and have the explosion pass overhead or go off nearby, then sure. But if you're unable to justifiably evade, dodge, dive for cover, or otherwise escape? Then no, you're toast.

Comment: That is about what I expected.The issue came up when a disguised bomb went off in a space mage's swimming pool while he was in it.

Comment: @Overthinks Does he have any Matter? A conjunctional Matter/Space effect could let the water absorb a lot of the force and have Space "curve" the rest around them.

Comment: Nope. Just Space and prime. He was ruled as dead, but I wanted to see anyone could dispute it.

Comment: @Overthinks The only thing I can think of is diving deep enough to avoid it. It depends on the size of the pool and the bomb.

Comment: Oh hes total dead now. I just wanted to know if just the space armour spell COULD have protect him. He didn't see anything coming and was totally reliant on that spell protecting him.

Comment: Did he have any reason or way to know the bomb was in the pool?  Seems like kind of a dick move if he was just getting some laps in and boom.